# Handle Telegram inline query from Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework, telegram-bot

I've created an bot in C# that uses the **Microsoft Bot Framework**, and I'm trying to handle an [inline query](https://core.telegram.org/bots/inline) from a **Telegram bot**.

Since inline queries are channel-specific (telegram only) functionality, they are not supported right out of the box. The [Bot Framework Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-channeldata?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#create-a-telegram-message) says the [answerInlineQuery](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inline-mode) method is supported. This can be used to answer to an inline query.

My question is: **How can I handle an inline query from telegram?**

So far I've only used the `OnMessageActivityAsync` function to handle incoming requests. This function does not get triggered once I start an inline query from telegram. Is there another function I can use to handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an activity is sent from Telegram to your bot, the associated data is contained within the `ChannelData` property of the incoming activity. For example,

```js
{
  type: 'message',
  id: '3451493078542633497',
  timestamp: 2020-11-12T01:53:42.890Z,
  serviceUrl: 'https://telegram.botframework.com/',  channelId: 'telegram',
  from: { id: '803***355', name: 'jdoe', role: 
'user' },
  conversation: { },
  recipient: { id: 'SomeBot', name: 'SomeBotName' },
  channelData: {
    update_id: 424***655,
    inline_query: {
      id: '345*************497',
      from: {
        id: 803613355,
        is_bot: false,
        first_name: 'John',
        last_name: 'Doe',
        username: 'jdoe',
        language_code: 'en'
      }
    },
    query: 'how do you do?',
    offset: ''
  }
},
  rawTimestamp: '2020-11-12T01:53:42.8907123Z',    
  callerId: 'urn:botframework:azure',
  text: 'how do you do?'
}
```

All activities that contain relevant activity types (e.g. "message", as shown below) are able to be captured in the activity handler of the same name. If you are not seeing "activity" in `OnMessageActivityAsync`, it is likely you don't have the handler configured correctly. As you haven't posted your activity handler code, it is impossible to say what the issue may be.

You can reference the [BotBuilder-Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/) for examples of how to set up your 'Bot'.cs file, located in the 'Bots' folders of every sample project.

Hope of help!

Comment: Thank you for your response! In the meantime, I traded in the Microsoft Bot Framework for a direct telegram implementation with https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot. This made it way easier to use all telegram features :)